# Dynamically reading .json file with multiple objects

Tags: c#, jquery, json, json.net

An application is providing me a .json file that contains an unknown amount of objects. On top of that, the objects content also changes quite a bit.

Here is an example of a json file:

```
{  
   "AVRunning":{  
      "Description":"Symantec Antivirus Service",
      "Status":true
   },
   "CorrectOU":{  
      "Description":"Server in Correct OU",
      "Status":true
   },
   "RoleAdGroups":{  
      "Result":true,
      "Group":"Server-Admin"
   },
   "DefaultAdGroups":[  
      {  
         "Result":true,
         "Group":"Domain Admins"
      },
      {  
         "Result":true,
         "Group":"Server-Admins"
      },
      {  
         "Result":true,
         "Group":"SERVERNAME-ADMINS"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is just an example of a json file. It could contain many more objects, as well as an unknown amount of content within it.

My question to you all, is how do I serialize this into a JSON object in c# once I read the content in as one gigantic string?

Also, I may be overcomplicationg the process here. Once I read this in, I want to pass the data to my view. If this can't be done in c#, would it be easier to do it in Jquery? Or should it be done there in the first place? The file that I am reading in is a local file, so I can't access the data directly in jquery.

I know JSON.NET is a possible tool, but from what I have read, I am not sure how to create the objects dynamically.

Comment: How will you process this data in your view? If it's dynamic by nature, how do you know what to do with it?

Comment: Please extract the second question (about passing the data into the view) into a new, separate question here on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jQuery makes it pretty simple (just `jQuery.parseJSON(<your string>);`).

I imagine JSON.NET has a parse function as well, but I haven't used that library, so I couldn't say for sure!

Comment: I am finding it best to parse the json dynamically using jquery rather than building partial views for each object. Using jquery it will be much easier since I am unsure how many objects my json file will contain, and the number of attributes for each object changes a lot as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define data types into which you want to deserialize json string:

```
public class ObjectWithDescriptionAndStatus
{
    public string Description;
    public string Status;
}

public class ObjectWithResultAndGroup
{
    public bool Result;
    public string Group;
}

public class MyObject
{
    public ObjectWithDescriptionAndStatus AVRunning;
    public ObjectWithDescriptionAndStatus CorrectOU;
    public ObjectWithResultAndGroup RoleAdGroups;
    public IList<ObjectWithResultAndGroup> DefaultAdGroups;
}
```

This is the simplest example, with all fields marked as `public` and named exactly as keys in the json (they can have arbitrary names but in that case you have to decorate each field with [`DataMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute and set its `Name` property to the actual name of the key).

Having data types defined, deserialization is a one-liner:

```
MyObject myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```